# How precise is Windows "Wireless Network Connection" dialog?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, usb, signal-strength

I'm having performance issues with my wireless connection. Pages load very slowly compared to a PC that's connected directly to the router, and performance in online games is at times very choppy/laggy. I realize that gaming on a wireless connection may not be the best of ideas, but there are times when gameplay is as smooth as silk, no lag at all, and then there are times like now, where everything stutters and lags.

Windows (specifically Windows 7 Ultimate) is reporting my signal strength at 3-4 bars and the speed fluctuates between 48 and 54 Mbps, but just exactly how reliable are the tools that ship with Windows? Are there more detailed tools out there that could possibly point out a problem that Windows isn't telling me about? As for troubleshooting I've already tried the usual, power cycling PC and router and modem, scanning for malware/viruses, and clearing browser cache/history, but everything comes out clean and the problem persists.

Comment: Note, the strength of the signal is different from the quality of the signal.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there more detailed tools out there that could possibly point out a problem that Windows isn't telling me about?

Of course there are. As you suspect, Windows includes only base tools (like Notepad or MSPaint) as opposed to full-featured products (like Word or Photoshop). System information tools are no different. When it comes to wireless, there are advanced tools that are free (like the kind hackers use to war-drive and such; search [SoureForge](http://sourceforge.net/) for [*wireless tools*](http://sourceforge.net/directory/os:windows/?q=wireless%20tools)) as well as commercial ones like those from [MetaGeek](http://www.metageek.net/products/).